# Background Color Of Text Disappears In Carousel,Why?

Tags: css, xml, html

There's a carousel at the top of [this blog](http://technopcarea.blogspot.com/),a kind of slider just below the menu containing text like Home,Suggestions etc. and there is text background added on the text appearing over the images,but it disappears when the image loads.Why ? can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display:block` property from the style it will works.

```
#carousel ul li a.slider_title {
    background: #A9A8A4;
    color: #fec700;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 13px Oswald;
    }
```

Comment: I tried it,it is working now but not the way I want,I want it to appear like you can see here-->[link](http://i.imgur.com/KE8YoFt.png)